# Show oldest when clicking on Outlook conversation?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

**Question:**
How can I make Outlook 2010 always **select the *oldest* unread message** in a conversation when expanding it?

**Details:**
Outlook 2010 inbox is configured to "Show as Conversations" (w/ "Always Expand Conversations" enabled). When a conversation has several unread messages and is *not* selected, only the most recent appears in my Inbox's list of messages by default (this is expected).

When I click on the conversation, it expands. The conversation's messages are sorted such that the most recent messages appear first/highest under the conversation and oldest messages appear last (this is to my liking).

But, when the conversation gets expanded, the *most recent* messages is selected and displayed in the Preview Pane, such that I'm viewing a message whose context is lost on me (b/c I haven't read all of the messages before it -- this is not to my liking).

Answer (score 8):

From the menu, View > View settings, then click 'Sort...', then select 'Conversation Index' from the dropbox and click 'Descending'.

Click OK, then OK again.

Comment: I saw this had a downvote, but this is actually the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: It depends on if you have "Use Classic Indented View" enabled.  This answer helped me find a configuration that I like to have newest last and the newest opened when you click on the conversation: Disable "Use Classic Indented View". In View > View settings, then click 'Sort...', select 'Received': 'Descending'.

Answer (score 4):

I just moved from Outlook 2011 for Mac to Outlook 2010. Outlook 2011 selects the oldest unread message when a conversation is expanded and sorts them by newest first. I have not been able to find the equivalence to this yet for Outlook 2010. The only thing I have found that is close is [Tip 965](http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/changing-outlook-2010s-conversation-view-message-order/) from [Outlook Tips](http://www.outlook-tips.net/):

> If you use the Classic Indented View, the messages within a
>   conversation are arranged in proper threading order within the
>   conversation, according to which message was replied to and the
>   received date. (Note that threading may not work as expected with
>   email from mailing lists or with mail sent from some email clients.
>   When outlook doesn't know where the message belongs in the thread, its
>   placed at the end of the thread.)

What I don't like about this is that my messages within a conversation are now sorted by oldest first but so far this is working fine for me.